# Linux + MySQL: How to make outputs/responses visible?

Tags: mysql, linux, webserver, debian

I'm very low in linux and try to list all databases in the console (using putty).

That's what I'm sending:

```
> mysql -u root -p
> [password]
> CREATE DATABASE [dbname]
> SHOW DATABASES
```

Thats the response:

```
>
```

It's weird, I'm getting just a new line as a response.
How can I tell linux/mysql to give me more information (failed/success)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a semicolon at the end of the line: `SHOW DATABASES;`

Comment: I did. Just had to wait a few minutes. ;-)